# How to search for an element in an XML payload using Xpath with Ballerina?

Tags: ballerina

Example: How to access the "city" using ballerina?

```
<h:People xmlns:h="http://www.test.com">
    <h:name>Anne</h:name>
    <h:address>
         <h:street>Main</h:street>
         <h:city>Miami</h:city>
    </h:address>
    <h:code>4</h:code>
</h:People>
```

I tried to use the select function, but it does not return anything to me.

```
payload.select("city")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the same method **selectDescendants** but since your second example does not have a namespace for the xml element, we have to use the empty namespace to lookup the child elements as below. Also, the **selectDescendants** returns an xml sequence with all matched elements. So to get the desired xml element, one option is to access it with correct index. The example code is as below.

```
import ballerina/io;

function main (string... args) {
    xml x = xml `<member>
    <sourcedid>
        <source>test1</source>
        <id>1234.567</id>
    </sourcedid>
    <entity>
        <sourcedid>
            <source>test2</source>
            <id>123</id>
        </sourcedid>
        <idtype>1</idtype>
    </entity>
    <entity>
        <sourcedid>
            <source>test</source>
            <id>123</id>
        </sourcedid>
        <idtype>2</idtype>
    </entity>
    </member>`;

    //Below would first find all the matched elements with "id" name and then get the first element
    xml x1 = x.selectDescendants("{}id")[0];
    io:println(x1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To search for children inside an xml tree you should use the `selectDescendants` method. From documentation for [xml type](https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/primitive-types.html#xml);

> `<xml> selectDescendants(string qname) returns (xml)`
>
> Searches in children recursively for elements matching the qualified
>   name and returns a sequence containing them all. Does not search
>   within a matched result.

Also you should use the fully qualified name (QName) of the element. In your sample the QName of the city element is `{http://www.test.com}city`

Here's a sample code.

```
import ballerina/io;

function main (string... args) {
    xml payload = xml `<h:People xmlns:h="http://www.test.com">
        <h:name>Anne</h:name>
        <h:address>
            <h:street>Main</h:street>
            <h:city>Miami</h:city>
        </h:address>
        <h:code>4</h:code>
    </h:People>`;

    io:println(payload.selectDescendants("{http://www.test.com}city"));
}
```

You can also make use of ballerina's built in support for [xml namespaces](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/xml-namespaces.html) and access your element in the following way.

```
xmlns "http://www.test.com" as h;
io:println(payload.selectDescendants(h:city));
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you answer my other question?

Comment: Hey Renan, Welcome to StackOverflow and ballerina! Please post a new question. Don't use the answers section for questions :)